# Can a cell phone app in iOS GET TEXT from another app?

Tags: ios

I want to build a cell phone app (app#1) in iOS who GETs TEXT from another app (app#2).
I can not control app#2.
The idea is to get text (plain text from app's window content) programmatically from apps like Whatsapp, email apps or a browser.
Is this a doable app? Can this be done?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "get text"? Do you just mean plain text, text messages, or something else?

Comment: yes, via copy and paste or via a sharing extension, no if you want your app to access it without user intervention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the third-party app provides any data sharing extensions or API you can get the data, else you can't programmatically access the data from other apps.

Remember each app runs in its own sand-boxed environment, so you can't access the data of another app.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless the other apps all provide an API that gives you the data you want. You can't open another app's file storage. Even if you could it's possible to be encrypted or change formats between versions.